# Fields in USR02 table

Tags: sap-basis

Prompt please what the difference between fields PWDCHGDATE and BCDA1; PWDLGNDATE and TRDAT table USR02 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the RSUSR200 program :

```
* 10.07.2008 D034973 (Note 1229694)                              7.00+
* for date of last logon it should be use only the field USR02-TRDAT
* and NOT PWDLGNDATE (Date of last logon try with correct password)
```

The same program check both field BCDA1 and PWDCHGDATE for the last password change.
It seems that there is a change from 6.0. Before that, bcda1 was solely used, whereas now there is a distinction between user type.

regards
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that bcda1 is for users that doesn't need to change their password (technical suers) and pwdchgdate is used for the policies. for example if you have a policy that you must change your password every 30 days.